# Weblogic 12.1.3, Jersey 2.5.1, how to enable MultiPartFeature : WELD-001408 Unsatisfied dependencies for type [Providers]

Tags: java, rest, jersey, weblogic, cdi

I have a web application running using JAX-RS and CDI on weblogic 12.1.3.

I want to enable the Multipart feature of Jersey but I get errors on deployment.

I use ResourceConfig to configure my REST application.
It is located in a seperate jar (let's call it commons) because it is used by multiple other applications.
And extended by another class in each application.

```
public abstract class RestConfig extends ResourceConfig {

public RestConfig() {

    property(CommonProperties.MOXY_JSON_FEATURE_DISABLE, true);
    register(JacksonFeature.class);
    register(RolesAllowedDynamicFeature.class);
    register(SecurityFilter.class);

    // here I register manually my resources classes because they are not discovered automatically, I don't why)
    registerRestPackages(COMMONS_REST_PACKAGES);
    registerRestPackages(getRestPackages());
    registerRestClasses(getRestLambdaClasses());

    // here is the important part that makes my applciation crash on startup
    register(MultiPartFeature.class);
}

}
```

And he class that extends this one :

```
@ApplicationPath("/api/")
public class RestApplication extends RestConfig {

    public RestApplication() {
        super();
    }
}
```

The jersey jar are in a shared lib according to the documentation : https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/wls/RESTF/use-jersey20-ri.htm#RESTF290

And I get ghis exception on startup :

```
weblogic.application.ModuleException: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408 Unsatisfied dependencies for type [Providers] with qualifiers [@Default] at injection point [[parameter 1] of [constructor] @Inject public org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.internal.MultiPartReaderServerSide(Providers, Provider<CloseableService>)]:org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException:WELD-001408 Unsatisfied dependencies for type [Providers] with qualifiers [@Default] at injection point [[parameter 1] of [constructor] @Inject public org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.internal.MultiPartReaderServerSide(Providers, Provider<CloseableService>)]
at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPoint(Validator.java:315)
at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPoint(Validator.java:284)
at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionTarget(Validator.java:342)
at org.jboss.weld.manager.InjectionTargetValidator.addInjectionTarget(InjectionTargetValidator.java:29)
at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.createInjectionTarget(BeanManagerImpl.java:943)
at weblogic.jaxrs.onwls.cdi.CdiComponentProvider$CdiFactory$2.<init>(CdiComponentProvider.java:201)
at weblogic.jaxrs.onwls.cdi.CdiComponentProvider$CdiFactory.<init>(CdiComponentProvider.java:180)
at weblogic.jaxrs.onwls.cdi.CdiComponentProvider.bind(CdiComponentProvider.java:262)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.bindWithComponentProvider(ApplicationHandler.java:874)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.bindProvidersAndResources(ApplicationHandler.java:804)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.initialize(ApplicationHandler.java:414)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.access$500(ApplicationHandler.java:162)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler$3.run(ApplicationHandler.java:304)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$2.call(Errors.java:289)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$2.call(Errors.java:286)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.processWithException(Errors.java:286)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:301)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:311)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:169)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:359)
at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:240)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletInitAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:337)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletInitAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:288)
at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.initServletInstance(StubSecurityHelper.java:98)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.createServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:92)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.createOneInstance(StubLifecycleHelper.java:69)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.<init>(StubLifecycleHelper.java:57)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.<init>(StubLifecycleHelper.java:36)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.initStubLifecycleHelper(ServletStubImpl.java:653)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.prepareServlet(ServletStubImpl.java:600)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadServlet(WebAppServletContext.java:1979)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.loadServletsOnStartup(WebAppServletContext.java:1956)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadResources(WebAppServletContext.java:1846)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.start(WebAppServletContext.java:2876)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1661)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:823)
at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$StartStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:360)
at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$StartStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:356)
at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42)
at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.start(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:138)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:124)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:216)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:211)
at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:73)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate(StartModulesFlow.java:24)
at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:729)
at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42)
at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:258)
at weblogic.application.internal.SingleModuleDeployment.activate(SingleModuleDeployment.java:48)
at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:165)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:80)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.activate(AbstractOperation.java:587)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.activateDeployment(ActivateOperation.java:150)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doCommit(ActivateOperation.java:116)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.commit(AbstractOperation.java:339)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentCommit(DeploymentManager.java:846)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.activateDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1275)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleCommit(DeploymentManager.java:442)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.commit(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:176)
at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doCommitCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:195)
at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$100(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:13)
at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$2.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:68)
at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:553)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:311)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:263)
```

The problem seems to be that the application cannot find a bean implementing the interface Providers.
There is JaxrsProviders class in jersey-common, but it does not seem to be detected by CDI.

This guy seems to have the same problem but it does not help me much : https://community.oracle.com/thread/3723819

If you have any idea...

Answer (score 1):

It should work. I've successfully used `Multipart` with weblogic 12.1.3 and Jersey 2.5.1.

Check that you're using the following dependency in `provided` scope :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Can you share your `weblogic.xml` or `weblogic-application.xml`?

Answer (score 0):

Please add below libraries in weblogc.xml

```
<wls:library-ref>
    <wls:library-name>wlp-rest-web-lib</wls:library-name>
    <wls:specification-version>10.3.2</wls:specification-version>
    <wls:implementation-version>10.3.2</wls:implementation-version>
    <wls:exact-match>false</wls:exact-match>
</wls:library-ref><wls:library-ref>
    <wls:library-name>p13n-rest-web-lib</wls:library-name>
    <wls:specification-version>10.3.2</wls:specification-version>
    <wls:implementation-version>10.3.2</wls:implementation-version>
    <wls:exact-match>false</wls:exact-match>
</wls:library-ref>
<wls:library-ref>
    <wls:library-name>jaxrs-framework-web-lib</wls:library-name>
    <wls:specification-version>10.3.2</wls:specification-version>
    <wls:implementation-version>10.3.2</wls:implementation-version>
    <wls:exact-match>false</wls:exact-match>
</wls:library-ref><wls:library-ref>
    <wls:library-name>jersey-web-lib</wls:library-name>
    <wls:specification-version>1.0</wls:specification-version>
    <wls:implementation-version>1.0.2</wls:implementation-version>
    <wls:exact-match>false</wls:exact-match>
</wls:library-ref>
```

and check the library from [url](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24983/version.htm#RESTF203).

If getting still error add jersey-media-multipart.jar file into your project lib directory.

```
You can change below thing in weblogic-application.xml at ear

 <prefer-application-packages>
    <package-name>com.sun.jersey.*</package-name>
    <package-name>org.glassfish.jersey.*</package-name>
    <package-name>org.glassfish.hk2.*</package-name>
    <package-name>org.jvnet.hk2.*</package-name>
    <package-name>jersey.repackaged.org.objectweb.asm.*</package-name>

    <package-name>com.sun.research.ws.wadl.*</package-name>
    <package-name>com.sun.ws.rs.ext.*</package-name>

    <package-name>org.codehaus.jackson.*</package-name>
    <package-name>com.fasterxml.jackson.*</package-name>

    <package-name>org.codehaus.jettison.*</package-name>

    <package-name>javax.ws.rs.*</package-name>

    <package-name>org.objectweb.asm.*</package-name>

    <package-name>antlr.*</package-name>

  </prefer-application-packages>
```

and [Weblogic 12c](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24983/version.htm#RESTF203)
Hope it helps.

Comment: I'm afraid this solution is for an older version of webogic.
I tried adding the jersey-multipart lib to the projet libs, but it does not solve my problem.

Comment: @Bob.This is not older version.Please see https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/wls/RESTF/use-jersey20-ri.htm#RESTF290

Comment: I tied to use a newer version as you suggested : new shared lib and all
But after doing that i got a ClassNotFoundException on javassist.util.proxy.ProxyObject

Comment: @Bob:May be javassist package is not available. So Please use mvn install to generate the library war and then make sure javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar

Comment: I could make jersey 2.25 work on my applciation but CDI is broken.

Comment: It's a JEE6 applciation with CDI 1.0.
I can inject a a service into a bean but I have to bind it manually...